# Is there a word for comparing theoretical predictions of a model against experimental results?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for *comparing theoretical predictions of a model against experimental results*?

In Science, first, we make some observations about a phenomenon, then model it & make predictions. Then we make experiments to check whether our model predicts reality. I'm looking for a word that describes this last point, *comparing the theoretical predictions of a model against the experimentally obtained results* to check whether the model predicts reality.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it concerns more the terminology of a certain field than language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the widely used *prove*, at least two other words are in scientific and computational use: *verification* and *validation*.

> *prove* = to show that something is true
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prove)

> *verification* = the process of testing or finding out if something is true, real, accurate, etc
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/verification)

> *validation* = proof that something is correct
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/validation)

A more refined distinction between the last words may be sought. For example, the two words are used in a substantial paper from Los Alamos National Laboratory. Here is a key figure from that paper::

[image]

https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/835920/

In this argument, verification is the process of ensuring that the computational model reflects accurately and in all circumstances the mathematics. Validation is the checking of the computed model outcomes against the experimental or observational reality.

In that way, it might be argued that successful *verification* and *validation* together *prove* the original model.